# How do I re-sort an array base on another array?

Tags: php, arrays

Example:

```
$arr = array('willion','kevien','john','smith');

$orderedArr = array('anne','bold','hellen','john','kevien','polm','smith','willion');
```

And I want to resort the `$arr` order based on `$orderdArr` order. How do I do that?

The result I expect:

> 'john','kevien','smith','willion'

the `$orderedArr` may be changed in order,So I want the $arr's order to be the same as $orderedArr.

I am sorry for simplifed my question.I think my $arr is much more complexity,the $arr's strucuture is: I use print_r() to show the array.

```
array（ [0] => array（[id]=>1 [name]=>willion）
        [1] => array（[id]=>2 [name]=>kevien）
        [2] => array（[id]=>3 [name]=>join)
      )
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What would be the expected result ....

Answer (score 3):

You can use `usort`

```
$order = array_flip($orderedArr);
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use($order) {
    return $order[$a] - $order[$b];
});
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => kevien
    [2] => smith
    [3] => willion
)
```

[See Live DEMO](http://eval.in/32910)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$arr` is always a subset of `$orderedArr`, you can use `array_intersect`:

```
$arr = array_intersect($orderedArr, $arr);
// $arr is now ['john', 'kevien', 'smith', 'willion']
```

Comment: Yes, $arr always a subset of $orderedArr.

Comment: Just a simple intersect then :)

Comment: but the $arr is a multi-dimention array,so..not the same data structure of the $orderedArr

Comment: @qinHaiXiang it wasn't in the original question :)

Answer (score 1):

use `foreach()` on the ordered array, append the values to a new array, but only if the exist in the original:

```
$arr = array('willion','kevien','john','smith');
$orderedArr = array('anne','bold','hellen','john','kevien','polm','smith','willion');

foreach($orderedArr as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value, $arr)){
        $newArr[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> Array ( [0] => john [1] => kevien [2] => smith [3] => willion )

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the id->name association of the $arr array you can simply do this.

```
$to_be_sorted=array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$person)
{
    $to_be_sorted[]=$person['name'];
}

$sorted = array_intersect($orderedArr, $to_be_sorted);

echo implode(",",$sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can loop in your order array and comparing to your array using `in_array` to build a new array in required order

```
$arr = array('willion','kevien','john','smith');

$orderedArr = array('anne','bold','hellen','john','kevien','polm','smith','willion');

$orderedUsers = array();
foreach ($orderedArr as $data) {
    if(in_array($data,$arr))
    {
        $orderedUsers[] = $data;
    }
}
```

this will output

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'john' (length=4)
  1 => string 'kevien' (length=6)
  2 => string 'smith' (length=5)
  3 => string 'willion' (length=7)
```

#### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/WfAf9b)